# Is there a way to audit documents that have been deleted without using Recycle Bin?

Tags: recycle-bin

We need to see what the document is, when it was deleted and who deleted it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have configured Configure Audit Settings as the following

- Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Site collection audit settings .

[image]

Then Try to use Audit Report

- Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Audit log reports.

[image]